# Python - Compare two list, get stuck inside try catch

Tags: python, json, for-loop

So I have been trying to make a monitor that compares two list - Old_list and new_list where the old_list saves the current json files that is saved now and a new_list that checks if there is a new item added it will add it into a new list

Json:

```
sample = {
    "threads": [
        {
            "seoTitle": "used cfood",
            "other_crap": "yeet"
        },
        {
            "seoTitle": "trucks",
            "other_crap": "it's a fox!"

        },
        {
            "seoTitle": "rockets",
            "other_crap": "i'm rocket man"
        },
        {
            "seoTitle": "helicopter",
            "other_crap": "for 007",
            "price": {
              "currentRetailPrice": 1249.95
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
old_list = []

    while True:
        try:
            url = 'www.helloworld.com'
            resp = s.get(url)

            new_list = resp.json()['threads']

            for item in new_list:
                if item['seoTitle'] not in old_list:
                    try:

                        print(item['seoTitle']) 
                        print('item['other_crap']))  # Print other information
                        old_list.append(item['seoTitle'])


                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                        print("ERROR")
                        time.sleep(5)
                        continue

            else:
                logger.warn("No new link found!")
                time.sleep(5)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            continue
```

What I noticed the problem is that I believe the program should make a compare between the two list which I did on:

```
for item in new_list:
    if item['seoTitle'] not in old_list:
```

but the problem is that everytime it checks the comparing it goes inside the try method and get stucks there everytime which I believe is not correct. What it supposed to do is that it there is nothing new then it should just do the **Else** method, What did I do wrong?

---- It prints everytime the

```
 print(item['seoTitle']) 
 print('item['other_crap']))  # Print other information
```

everytime instead of going to **else:** method.

Comment: A few notes. Your outermost try-except is not inside the `for` loop, so `continue` will throw an Exception there. Also, your `else` statement is misaligned, could have just been from trying to format the code. Lastly, your `while` loop will never exit, because there is no `break` command when the `for` loop completes

Comment: Would you please make an example of what you mean, I don't quite get what you mean. However the while loop should be on forever because im doing such called monitor where I check the list. so breaking it would be abit useless for the checking. I dont think it has to do with server because it does hit the `else` when its done but then when it runs again it loops inside the `forloop -> try` function. Which it shouldn't if there is no new item, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it gets stuck inside the `try/except`. I think it does the append, then loops back to the top and gets stuck because something happens to the network communications, so it just hangs waiting for the server. Most likely.

But you're not very precise about what you're observing, so it's hard to tell. We also don't know what you're using to connect to the server, which makes things tricky. What is `s`? You may be able to set a socket timeout that makes it return after a certain time without hanging forever.

A print statement up with the `s.get(url)` would help. Also, if you showed the actual output that would also help.

Comment: Oh im sorry, the s stands for `s = requests.Session()` basically a normal requests. I dont think it has to do with server because it does hit the `else` when its done but then when it runs again it loops inside the `forloop -> try` function. Which it shouldn't if there is no new item, correct?

Comment: You need more data, instead of trying to guess. Do a print on the GET, and also print the new_list. Then run it and let's see what the output is. Should be easy to figure out what's going on then.

Comment: Basically my main idea is that it should not go inside the if statement if there is no new item which means it should go to the else statement if there is no item and sleep and then repeat again.

Comment: That's correct. But that doesn't tell you anything. Put in some more prints and run it again. Then you will learn something.

Comment: Oh damn, You might be actually right. if you check the `new_list = resp.json()['threads']`that would print out the whole json file while I add into the `old_list` only the seoTitle.. Should that matter?